What is the use of field_id in a column when creating a table with pyiceberg
When creating a table using pyiceberg a column is represented by a NestedField with an attribute field_id. When defining a Partition based on a timestamp or date field the source_id is not the field_id.
I created a table with a bunch of columns and the Partition worked only when the source_id is the index of the column (index starting at 1). Why is this the case and what is the use of the field_id?

Partitioning works with source_id because it uses the column's position, not its field_id.

Thanks, that answers part of my question, but what is the use of the field_id?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
